# Symfony production stage not working

Tags: symfony1

I've got a module named content, and its in the app frontend. When I go to  `localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/content` , I get the page showing up just fine without errors. But without the  `/frontend_dev.php`  I cant access the page.

What can be wrong? Here is my frontend settings.yml:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        false

dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false

test:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        
    cache:                  false
    web_debug:              false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false

all:
  .settings:
    # Form security secret (CSRF protection)
    csrf_secret:            ecca0f5ffb475363f798d55871546583f60f971f

    # Output escaping settings
    escaping_strategy:      true
    escaping_method:        ESC_SPECIALCHARS

    # Enable the database manager
    use_database:           true


    enable_modules: [default, sfGuardAuth]
```

What I get is a 404 from the web server. Cleared the symfony cache, did not work. And did a chown -R username projectdirectory.

The address I mean is  `localhost:8080/module/action` , does not work for anything. But it works like that on another server I'm running a symfony project.

EDIT:
I'm still new to symfony. I managed to enter with  `localhost:8080/index.php/module/action` . But how can I remove the index.php from the routing rules? Thanks

Thanks

Comment: 2 things. 1. Clear the cache. 2. See if `index.php` is even being called. It's possible that the `.htaccess` redirection isn't working.

Comment: When you say "But without the `/frontend_dev.php` I cant access the page", what *exact* URL are you requesting? And when you say you can't access the page, what's the problem? An error message, a 404? If it's a 404, is it Symfony's custom 404, or the default web server's 404?

Comment: I cleared the cache, nothing happened. I mean just localhost:8080/content. Index.php is beeing called I think. What worked tho was to change the route so that content is my homepage, and then clear the cache...
And yes, its a 404, from the default web server. And, I also did a chown -R <myusername> projectdirectory. Dont get it why only dev stage is working :(

Comment: you have `no_script_name` set to true in the `prod` env so you shouldnt need the `index.php` in the url. If youre getting the default webserver 404 then its not going to index.php at all... either because it doesnt exist, or because mod_rewrite is mis-configured somehow. If it was a permissions issue you would get a 403 most likely...

Comment: I do need the index.php, that is the problem, even when the no_script_name is set to true in prod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `mod_rewrite` isnt fired up, do you have it enabled? Is it even installed?

You can check with:

`/your/path/to/httpd -M | grep rewrite`

Or you could remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` tags around the rewrite rules in `.htaccess`. After doing this apache will generate a configuration error if mod_rewrite isnt installed and/or enabled.

If you have mod rewrite installed then make sure its directives can be used from `.htaccess` You should have something like the following in your vhost (or httpd.conf):

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/project/web">
  AllowOverride All
  # possibly other rules....
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like the only possible answer. @Johannes, it's the rewrite rules in the web/.htaccess file that will change a request for localhost:8080/module/action into a request for index.php -- the final RewriteRule in the default Symfony .htaccess file is the bit that does this particular magic. If your .htaccess file is missing, or unreadable by the webserver, or as prodigitalson says, Apache isn't configured to enable/allow the rewrite using mod_rewrite, then this would definitely cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks, now I learned something. I made a symlink from the available to enabled mods in /etc/apache2. Then I edited /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default to AllowOverride All.

Comment: @Johannes (off-topic!) Are you making those symlinks manually? There's probably an "a2enmod" command available to do the work for you, you know...

Comment: Yes, never heard of an a2enmod :D